# Can I influence the properties of multipe Controls with a single Trigger?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a custom menu bar in my WPF application. To highlight the background I use a mouse IsMouseOver trigger on a StackPanel. However, Within the StackPane item is a Grid so I can assign a narrow yellow line at the bottom of the StackPanel item. The trigger is invoked at the StackPanel item and I need to influence a property of a border within a grid within the StackPanel item.

I am searching for all kinds of stuff, but I can't find what I need. Maybe I am looking at it the wrong way.

`

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="VsMenuTop" TargetType="MenuItem">
        <StackPanel TextBlock.FontSize="120px" Height="80">
            <!-- label, icons, etc. -->
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource LableText}"  
  Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Margin="20px" />

                <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="{StaticResource 
  EyYellowBrush}" Margin="0 0 0 -3"/>

            </Grid>

            <!-- sub items -->
            <Popup IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}" 
 AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="White" 
  BorderBrush="#E0E0E0">
                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                </Border>
            </Popup>
            <StackPanel.Style>
                <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"  Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Style>
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

`   Can someone point me to a solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the target controls `x:Name` attributes. Move the trigger to ControlTemplate.Triggers, and use the TargetName attribute of the Setters to specify which target control you want them to apply to.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="VsMenuTop" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <StackPanel TextBlock.FontSize="120px" Height="80" x:Name="MyStackPanel">
        <!-- label, icons, etc. -->
        <Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="5" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource LableText}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Margin="20px" />

            <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="{StaticResource EyYellowBrush}" Margin="0 0 0 -3"/>

        </Grid>

        <!-- sub items -->
        <Popup IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="White" BorderBrush="#E0E0E0">
                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </StackPanel>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger SourceName="MyStackPanel" Property="IsMouseOver"  Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="MyStackPanel" Property="Background" Value="Black" />
            <Setter TargetName="MyGrid" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```